# Unit Testing for Linq Method

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a method for which I have to write a Unit Test. This method uses Database context to retrieve details from database.

Now I am thinking of ways to mock this database context and test remaining LINQ code.

Similarly I have other methods which has some logic and some LINQ queries I want to Unit test them as well.

```
public class OrderService
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public OrderService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int OrderCount(int orderId)
    {
        var count = _context.Orders.Where(x=>x.orderId==orderId).ToList().Count;
    }
}
```

How should I approach this situation?

This is common scenario faced by developers still there is not much information available on this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You should mock the code to retrieve data from database. Unit test doesn’t work in real database

Comment: What if that code has many business logic along with retrieving the data from the database?

Comment: You could use in-memory db

Comment: Another way is creating wrapper on dbcontext.Anyway  I would  go with in-memory db

Comment: seems like an interesting idea, do you have any reference or link on this.

Comment: @vndpal Which EF version are you using?

Comment: EF 6.0, but my question revolves around unit testing of LINQ regardless of the version.

Comment: I echo the suggestion of @BasilKosovan: use a DbContext with a different provider. However, I prefer to use the Sqlite provider with the ':memory:' option. I have come across a couple of instances where the in-memory provider will handle the query just fine but any real database will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to separate the fact that your data is in a database from the way that you want to fetch your data.

In other words: your LINQ methods should have `IQueryable<...>` as input. Not a DbContext.

Apart from the fact that this will make your unit testing a piece of cake, it will also allow you to reuse your LINQ handling for data from a different source, for instance a different database, or a CSV-file, or XML, or maybe just from a Dictionary.

I create an extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, consider to read [Extension Methods Demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

```
public static int Count(this IQueryable<Order> orders, int orderId)
{
    return orders.Where(order=>order.orderId==orderId).Count();
}
```

Usage:

```
int orderId = this.ReadOrderId();
using (var dbContext = new MyOrderContext(...))
{
    return dbContext.Orders.Count(orderId);
}
```

Maybe `CountByOrderId` is a better name.

And for your unit test, for example to test the CountByOrderId of an empty order collection:

```
int orderId = 4;
var emptyOrderCollection = Enumerable.Empty<Order>();
int orderCount = emptyOrderCollection.CountByOrderId(orderId);
Assert.AreEqual(..., orderCount);
```

By the way, did you notice that I removed `ToList`? It is a bit of wasting processing power to first create a List, and then only use the number of elements in it, then throw away the list.

### Generic solution

If you want to make your count method even more generic, for instance to count also Products with a certain price, or Students of a certain BirthYear:

```
public static CountByProperty<TSource, TPropery>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource,TProperty>> propertySelector,
    TProperty value)
{
    return source.Where(s=>propertySelector(s)==value).Count();
}
```

Usage:

```
return dbContext.Orders.CountByProperty(order => order.OrderId, 4);
```

Or count the Products that have a price of exactly $1.00:

```
return dbContext.Products.CountByProperty(product => product.Price, 1.00);
```

Comment: `Where(s=>propertySelector(s)==value)` will not work. You can try it by yourself.

Comment: If the method with a propertySelector doesn't work, consider to use `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate` as a parameter. The predicate must be something like `product => product.Price == 1.00`